# Is it possible to have private methods and properties visible to subclasses?

Tags: objective-c

What I'm going for here is basically a class Extension that is also visible to subclasses.  I suppose the effect could be accomplished by declaring the private methods and properties in a separate Category file with its own @implementation block independent of the class's.  The superclass and each subclass could then #import the header. That's the best I can think of, but it feels like unnecessary file pollution, and the practice of realizing private methods with Categories has largely been superseded by class Extensions.  I'm thinking it's not possible, but I'm asking on the off-chance that someone cooler than me has thought of a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow your own suggestion (declaring the private methods in a separate header), but you can use an extension if you'd prefer, rather than a category.

Apple does exactly this with UIGestureRecognizer. Take a look in UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h.

Comment: Yeah, the same philosophy could work with an Extension, but no matter how you slice it, it's an extra code file?

Comment: It's either that, or you could do some macro trickery. Like doing `#ifdef MY_CLASS_PRIVATE` before your subclass stuff and then use `#define MY_CLASS_PRIVATE\n#import <MyClass.h>` in your implementation and subclasses. I'd tend to prefer the extra file, though, because it's more clear what a subclass should do.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Yeah, I'd take the extra file as well. It's funny how the option is more appealing now that you've pointed out Apple uses it.  Thanks.